# 3 axis Coordinate system in processing 3.2.4

Tags: 3d, processing

I want to make a program that draws a three axis coordinate system in Processing and takes as input a point's coordinates A(x,y,z) and displays it in the three axis coordinate system, can anyone here provide me with a code i could start with ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily draw an axis using the [line()](https://processing.org/reference/line_.html) function and passing two pairs of x,y,z coordinates (the "from" and "to" points of the line in 3D).

Drawing 3 lines and colouring each axis with a colour (e.g. X,Y,Z as R,G,B) should do:

```
void drawAxes(float size){
  //X  - red
  stroke(192,0,0);
  line(0,0,0,size,0,0);
  //Y - green
  stroke(0,192,0);
  line(0,0,0,0,size,0);
  //Z - blue
  stroke(0,0,192);
  line(0,0,0,0,0,size);
}
```

If you plan to use multiple coordinate systems, it's worth reading the [2D transformations tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/). The same concepts apply to 3D as well in terms of isolating and nesting coordinate systems using [pushMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html)/[popMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) calls:

```
PVector a = new PVector(100,50,20);

void setup(){
  size(400,400,P3D);
  strokeWeight(3);
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  //draw original coordinate system
  drawAxes(100);
  //draw from centre and rotate with mouse
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  rotateX(map(mouseY,0,height,-PI,PI));
  rotateY(map(mouseX,0,width,PI,-PI));

  //draw centred coordinate system
  drawAxes(100);

  //isolate coordinate system for A point
  pushMatrix();
  translate(a.x,a.y,a.z);
  //draw translated A point
  drawAxes(50);
  popMatrix();
}
void drawAxes(float size){
  //X  - red
  stroke(192,0,0);
  line(0,0,0,size,0,0);
  //Y - green
  stroke(0,192,0);
  line(0,0,0,0,size,0);
  //Z - blue
  stroke(0,0,192);
  line(0,0,0,0,0,size);
}
```

You can run a [p5.js preview](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/full/HkQoQTAvl) bellow:

```html
<iframe width="400" height="400" src="https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/embed/HkQoQTAvl" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a play around with it, it seems to be switching and reversing axis-es in between the first and second given points on a line, god knows why, but its what you gotta do to make it work as expected.  so a line on the x axis is line(100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0); and the y axis is line(0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0);. so it kinda reverses everything each time in between declared points from where you'd expect them to be from the processing axis diagram.